# Multiple Foreign Key Constraint errors throughout my mock Database, referencing wrong data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get some errors from this SQL code. I am making a mock database for practice.  I have looked at some work around and have redone the code a few times.

Everything has been created in order (I believe). Any help would be great! Am I referencing the incorrect tables/columns?  Am I referencing different Data types that shouldn't be?

Here are the errors I get:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 186
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_bookid". The conflict occurred in database "db_City_Library", table "dbo.Books", column 'BookID'.
>
> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 63
> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_publisher_name_books". The conflict occurred in database "db_City_Library", table "dbo.Publisher",

Code:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_City_Library
USE db_City_Library

CREATE TABLE Library_Branch 
(
    BranchID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    BranchName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    BranchAddress varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE Book_Copies 
(
    BookID INT NOT NULL,--FK Done
    BranchID INT NOT NULL, --FK DONE
    Number_Of_Copies INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Books 
(
    BookID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (10000, 1),
    Title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PublisherName VARCHAR(100) --FK Done
);

CREATE TABLE Book_Authors 
(
    BookID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_book_id REFERENCES Books(BookID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    AuthorName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Publisher 
(
    PublisherName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Phone VARCHAR(15)
);

-- all code above executed

-- Customer information tables
CREATE TABLE Borrower 
(
    CardNo INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (100, 1),
    Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Phone VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Book_Loans 
(
    BookID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_bookid REFERENCES Books(BookID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    BranchID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_branch_id REFERENCES Library_Branch(BranchID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CardNo INT NOt NULL CONSTRAINT fk_card_no REFERENCES Borrower(CardNo) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    DateOut DATE NOT NULL,
    DateIn DATE NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE Book_Copies
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_branch_id_book_copies 
    FOREIGN KEY (BranchID) REFERENCES Library_Branch(BranchID) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Book_Copies
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_book_ID_book_copies 
    FOREIGN KEY (BookID) REFERENCES Books(BookID) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Books
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_publisher_name_books
    FOREIGN KEY (PublisherName) REFERENCES Publisher(PublisherName) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

INSERT INTO Library_Branch (BranchName, BranchAddress)
VALUES ('Sharpstown', '121 Sharpstown Blvd'),
       ('Randolph', '17 Tamari Court'),
       ('Waterbury', '46 Henry Hough Rd'),
       ('Stowe', '192 Thomas Lane'),
       ('Burlington', '142 South Winooski Ave'),
       ('South Burlington', '190 South Willard Ave');

SELECT * FROM Publisher

INSERT INTO Borrower (Name, Address, Phone)
VALUES ('John Doe', '12 Thatplace place', '973-598-5837'),
       ('Justin Doughnut', '91 Thisplace place', '973-598-5832'),
       ('Jennifer Dee', '64 Programmer ave', '973-598-5981'),
       ('Katy Perry', '12 Thisandthatplace rd', '973-598-5837'),
       ('Louie Labrador', '75 State Route 109', '971-528-5997'),
       ('Susana Lander', '36 whoknows place', '575-555-9090'),
       ('Chee Mann', '90 Whoknows plaza', '802-253-9090'),
       ('Johnny Dee', '12 1st ave', '878-889-1010');

INSERT INTO Publisher (PublisherName, Address, Phone)
VALUES ('Pottermore Publishing', 'London, UK', '1-800-888-9087'),
       ('Bantam Spectra', 'New York, NY', '212-518-9090'),
       ('Scribner', 'New York, NY', '212-345-9090'),
       ('Allen & Unwin', 'Crows Nest, AU', '1-800-909-9813'),
       ('Penguin Random House', 'New York, NY', '1-800-733-3000'),
       ('Hatchette Livre', 'Paris France', '1-800-759-0190'),
       ('HarperCollins', 'New York, NY', '1-800-242-7737'),
       ('MacMillan Publishers', 'New York, NY', '1-800-901-9876'),
       ('Simon & Schuster', 'New York, NY', '1-866-506-1949'),
       ('McGraw-Hill Education', 'New York, NY', '1-800-338-3987');

SELECT * FROM Publisher;
SELECT* FROM Books

INSERT INTO Books (Title, PublisherName)
VALUES ('Harry Potter and the Halfblood Prince', 'Pottermore Publishing'),
       ('Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban', 'Pottermore Publishing'),
       ('Fire & Blood', 'Bantam Spectra'),
       ('A song of Ice and Fire', 'Bantam Spectra'),
       ('It', 'Scribner'),
       ('The Outsider', 'Scribner'),
       ('Different Seasons', 'Scribner'),
       ('The Hobbit', 'Allen & Unwin'),
       ('The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring', 'Allen & Unwin'),
       ('The Lord of the Rings: The Twin Towers', 'Allen & Unwin'),
       ('The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', 'Allen & Unwin'),
       ('The Guardians', 'Penguin Random House'),
       ('Talking to Strangers', 'Hachette Livre'),
       ('On the Come Up', 'HarperCollins'),
       ('Me', 'MacMillan Publishers'),
       ('The Institute', 'Simon & Schuster'),
       ('SAT/ACT Prep Book', 'McGraw-Hill Education'),
       ('Sleeping Beauties', 'Scribner'),
       ('Harry Potter and the Sorcerers Stone', 'Pottermore Publishing'),
       ('Howerd Stern Comes Again', 'Simon & Schuster');

INSERT INTO Books (Title, PublisherName)
VALUES ('The Lost Tribe', 'Hatchette Livre');

SELECT * FROM Book_Authors
SELECT * FROM Books

INSERT INTO Book_Authors (BookID, AuthorName)
VALUES (10000, 'J.K. Rawling'),
       (10001, 'J.K. Rawling'),
       (10002, 'George R.R. Martin'),
       (10003, 'George R.R. Martin'),
       (10004, 'Stephen King'),
       (10005, 'Stephen King'),
       (10007, 'J. R. R. Tolkein'),
       (10008, 'J. R. R. Tolkein'),
       (10009, 'J. R. R. Tolkein'),
       (10010, 'J. R. R. Tolkein');

SELECT * FROM Book_Copies
SELECT* FROM Books
SELECT * FROM Library_Branch

INSERT INTO Book_Copies (BookID, BranchID, Number_Of_Copies)
VALUES (10002, 1, 4), (10004, 2, 2), (10001, 1, 6),
       (10005, 3, 3), (10001, 2, 3), (10007, 2, 2), 
       (10007, 3, 2), (10007, 4, 2), (10007, 5, 2),
       (10008, 3, 2), (10009, 4, 2), (10010, 5, 2),
       (10010, 6, 2), (10007, 1, 2);

SELECT * FROM Books
SELECT * FROM Library_Branch
SELECT * FROM Borrower

INSERT INTO Book_Loans (BookID, BranchID, CardNo, DateOut, DateIn)
VALUES (1000, 1, 101, '2020-04-21', '2020-05-21'),
       (1002, 2, 100, '2020-03-12', '2020-04-12'),
       (1000, 3, 102, '2020-04-01', '2020-05-01'),
       (1000, 1, 101, '2020-05-02', '2020-06-02'),
       (1000, 1, 104, '2020-05-20', '2020-06-20'),
       (1000, 5, 107, '2020-05-20', '2020-06-20'),
       (1000, 6, 105, '2020-04-17', '2020-05-17'),
       (1000, 3, 102, '2020-06-01', '2020-07-01'),
       (1000, 4, 102, '2020-01-01', '2020-02-01'),
       (1000, 3, 107, '2020-05-22', '2020-06-22');
```

Comment: Hey Dale,  Sorry about that!  Will remove now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is really easy to learn when you want to! (I see your syntax is = sql, correct me if I'm wrong lol)

I see you are getting those errors because your constraints you did made.

To fix the issue you can use the `ALTER TABLE tableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT constraintName` for a specific constraint or `ALTER TABLE tableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL` for all constraints. 
 
And you can again just enable them by `ALTER TABLE tableName WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT constraintName` for a specific constraint or `ALTER TABLE tableName WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL` for all constraints.

 I did re-write all of the above per section in a SQLFIDDLE for you... I did only fix the first issue for you by using the method above... I did not touch the others since you want to learn. Let me know if you got stuck so I can help you where you got stuck.
 [DBFiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=784009148813319322f3e2a6e1f58c7d)

**That will be the EASY solutions and not long term solution**

 If you want a long term solution wait for my edits below:

---

**Update #1**
First fixed issue

```
-- Update: #1 You are making PublisherName PK = UNIQUE so it can't be listed more than one time
CREATE TABLE Publisher (
PublisherName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, --PRIMARY KEY,
Address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
Phone VARCHAR(15)
);
```

So what you need to do here is;

1. Choose another PK/Delete the PK from PublisherName
2. Don't use the same publisher, which is obviusly not the best option...

    [DBFiddle with update 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a64e2df56cd4821bed2179e01d5fb197)

---

**Update 2**

 So the `fk_publisher_name_books` constraint would not work anymore since publisher_name is not PK/unique anymore. So we need to figure out a unique one... 
We can choose between the address and the phone. I did choose the phone since every phone = one unique publisher. I did change the constraint to `fk_phone_books` and changed the FK & the references.

 That would be not finished if we also don't change the structure of the table books;

```
CREATE TABLE Books (
    BookID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(10000,1),
    Title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PublisherName VARCHAR(100), --FK not good :(
    Phone VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL --FK done right :P
    );
```

[New DBFiddle with Update2 on it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=509b85602aeb923fd6105b009b9cc5b6)

---

**Conclusion**

I would like to spend more time to fix the issues but from what I see you need to rewrite the architecture of your database.

 **Make a Entity Relationship Diagram** and see what is PK and what is FK. 

 Making an ERD at the first place is way better than writig/creating the database/tables and after that get tons of errors and search for the bad PK and FK ^^

Comment: I hope this will help you mate! And don't forget: First the architecture plan after that the physical database making/creating....

Comment: Also I did try to make the Title PK but still you would need to rewrite a lot of tables and INSERTS structures... So best way use ERD and check what you should put as PK and FK. Also never forget PK = UNIQUE, so don't put something to be PK if you think it would be used more than one time.

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much for you help.  I do have a full ERD for this project where the designated PK is for the PublisherName in the Publisher table....How ever, if I were to remove this PK designation, would that be a fix as well?  Or would I need to have a PK in that table?

Comment: You don't need to have a PK in a table unless you are trying to link them. Also if you remove the PK you also need to check if there is any FK linked to that PK :)

Answer (score 0):

Your script can get into error easily. I would suggest you to always follow the below order for scripts running, if you are generating scripts yourself.

1. CREATE TABLE DDL scripts. Have Check constraints inline in the CREATE TABLE scripts
2. Primary Key constraint DDL scripts. ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT ... PRIMARY KEY...
3. Foreign Key constraint DDL scripts. ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY ... REFERENCES ...
4. INSERT DML scripts for Parent tables. The data which are referenced by child tables.
5. INSERT DML scripts for Child tables. The data which are depending on parent tables data.

With the above approach, you can avoid PK, FK errors while creating them (DDL) and avoid FK errors in child tables (DML)

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I appreciate the input!

Comment: if it helped you, upvote it, so it will be helpful for others in future